# Does anyone know the function of this Android class? "com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.db"?

Tags: android, logcat, tiktoktemplate

I was using Android Studio Logcat to debug my own app and came across some logs involving "com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.db" class. Is this related to tiktok? I never installed the app on my phone.

Comment: Hard to tell... what's your phone? Also take a look at the apps installed on your device including system apps, take a look at the file explorer in Android Studio, etc.

Comment: It's realme6, checked all installed app

Comment: Today I noticed it too. A very long time ago I had installed it on my phone. However, now it is not on my phone. But I did see logs today. That is really surprising.     Trace AmbientBroadcastReceiverServiceClientImpl#onReceive timed out after ..  ms. Complete trace: # com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.cx@f..
    com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.db:

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I had similar logs in my Logcat. You can get the process which creates the log by using adb and matching the process number (PID) to the number in the log. Use this command to list the Android processes:

```
adb shell ps -A
```

In my case, these were the processes which created the TikTok logs:

- com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:interactor
- com.google.android.apps.wellbeing
- com.google.android.apps.fitness

It looks like they all come from Google apps (and not TikTok). Also, the logs say **com.google.apps.tiktok.***, if it was actually TikTok, it would be something like **com.tiktok.***.

I also found this tweet:
https://twitter.com/imShreyasPatil/status/1320399162651803648

And the Twitter user @pratik13butani commented:

> Tiktok is an internal component in Google used by many of the apps, it was written and named like that before the social network existed and is absolutely unrelated.

So it seems like it is just an internal Google component.

Comment: That's good to know, but it's bothersome that it constantly crashes (meaning almost every second, and when I interact it's even spraying crashes)