# Why is app in the Google developer console crashing with tiktok appearing in an http call?

Tags: http, xamarin.forms, google-play

My Xamarin Forms app in the Google Play console is crashing with the following stack trace (only a single line is given to me):

```
ANR in com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search;PID: 15339;Broadcast of Intent { act=android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED flg=0x5000010 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.apps.tiktok.account.data.device.DeviceAccountsChangedReceiver_Receiver };
```

It occurs when the user is doing a C# HttpClient request to a website.

The last second of logcat logs are as below. For some reason the word tiktok is appearing in the logs and the stack trace above. I have no idea why because I am definitely not making any reference whatsoever to tiktok in my code.

Any ideas for why this crash might be occurring?

```
07-10 05:48:50.058: E/ActivityManager(1570):    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact$broadcastIntent$(IActivityManager.java:10180)
07-10 05:48:50.058: E/ActivityManager(1570):    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:167)
07-10 05:48:50.058: E/ActivityManager(1570):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3374)
07-10 05:48:50.058: E/ActivityManager(1570):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
07-10 05:48:50.065: E/ActivityManager(1570): Sending non-protected broadcast jp.co.sharp.android.downloadfont.DLFontService.ACTION_FONT_REMOVED from system 3591:jp.co.sharp.android.downloadfont/1000 pkg jp.co.sharp.android.downloadfont
07-10 05:48:50.065: E/ActivityManager(1570): java.lang.Throwable
07-10 05:48:50.065: E/ActivityManager(1570):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:21515)
07-10 05:48:50.065: E/ActivityManager(1570):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:22119)
07-10 05:48:50.065: E/ActivityManager(1570):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:22261)
07-10 05:48:50.065: E/ActivityManager(1570):    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact$broadcastIntent$(IActivityManager.java:10180)
07-10 05:48:50.065: E/ActivityManager(1570):    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:167)
07-10 05:48:50.065: E/ActivityManager(1570):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3374)
07-10 05:48:50.065: E/ActivityManager(1570):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
07-10 05:48:50.074: W/ContextImpl(3591): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1005 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:444 jp.co.sharp.android.downloadfont.DLFontService.DLFontService.sendBroadcastIntent:1059 jp.co.sharp.android.downloadfont.DLFontService.DLFontService.access$300:56 jp.co.sharp.android.downloadfont.DLFontService.DLFontService$2.delFont:1321 
07-10 05:48:50.074: W/BroadcastQueue(1570): Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
07-10 05:48:50.074: W/BroadcastQueue(1570): Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
07-10 05:48:50.075: W/BroadcastQueue(1570): Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
07-10 05:48:50.075: E/ActivityManager(1570): Sending non-protected broadcast com.android.settings.DisplayFontTypeSettings.ACTION_FONTLIST_UPDATE from system 3591:jp.co.sharp.android.downloadfont/1000 pkg jp.co.sharp.android.downloadfont
07-10 05:48:50.075: E/ActivityManager(1570): java.lang.Throwable
07-10 05:48:50.075: E/ActivityManager(1570):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:21515)
07-10 05:48:50.075: E/ActivityManager(1570):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:22119)
07-10 05:48:50.075: E/ActivityManager(1570):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:22261)
07-10 05:48:50.075: E/ActivityManager(1570):    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact$broadcastIntent$(IActivityManager.java:10180)
07-10 05:48:50.075: E/ActivityManager(1570):    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:167)
07-10 05:48:50.075: E/ActivityManager(1570):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3374)
07-10 05:48:50.075: E/ActivityManager(1570):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
07-10 05:48:50.085: W/BroadcastQueue(1570): Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
07-10 05:48:50.088: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): mCompatibilityFlags - 0
07-10 05:48:50.088: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationDensity - 480
07-10 05:48:50.088: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationScale - 1.0
07-10 05:48:50.090: W/BroadcastQueue(1570): Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
07-10 05:48:50.091: W/BroadcastQueue(1570): Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
07-10 05:48:50.096: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): mCompatibilityFlags - 0
07-10 05:48:50.096: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationDensity - 480
07-10 05:48:50.096: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationScale - 1.0
07-10 05:48:50.114: W/System.err(3461): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: androidx.test.tools.crawler
07-10 05:48:50.115: W/System.err(3461):     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfoAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:181)
07-10 05:48:50.115: W/System.err(3461):     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:152)
07-10 05:48:50.115: W/System.err(3461):     at com.facebook.oxygen.appmanager.ui.offline.b.a_(OfflineInstallJobCleanup.java:26)
07-10 05:48:50.115: W/System.err(3461):     at com.facebook.oxygen.common.packages.b.c.a(DeltaPackageListenerDispatcher.java:46)
07-10 05:48:50.115: W/System.err(3461):     at com.facebook.oxygen.common.packages.b.e.a(DeltaPackageTracker.java:84)
07-10 05:48:50.115: W/System.err(3461):     at com.facebook.oxygen.common.packages.b.f.b(DeltaPackageWorker.java:99)
07-10 05:48:50.115: W/System.err(3461):     at com.facebook.oxygen.common.packages.b.f.a(DeltaPackageWorker.java:82)
07-10 05:48:50.115: W/System.err(3461):     at com.facebook.oxygen.common.jobqueue.a.c(JobQueueManager.java:297)
07-10 05:48:50.115: W/System.err(3461):     at com.facebook.oxygen.common.jobqueue.a.b(JobQueueManager.java:270)
07-10 05:48:50.115: W/System.err(3461):     at com.facebook.oxygen.common.jobqueue.JobQueueService.a(JobQueueService.java:84)
07-10 05:48:50.115: W/System.err(3461):     at androidx.core.app.j$a.a(JobIntentService.java:397)
07-10 05:48:50.115: W/System.err(3461):     at androidx.core.app.j$a.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:387)
07-10 05:48:50.115: W/System.err(3461):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
07-10 05:48:50.115: W/System.err(3461):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
07-10 05:48:50.115: W/System.err(3461):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
07-10 05:48:50.115: W/System.err(3461):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
07-10 05:48:50.115: W/System.err(3461):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
07-10 05:48:50.118: W/System.err(3461): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.MyApp.MyApp
07-10 05:48:50.118: W/System.err(3461):     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfoAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:181)
07-10 05:48:50.118: W/System.err(3461):     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:152)
07-10 05:48:50.118: W/System.err(3461):     at com.facebook.oxygen.appmanager.ui.offline.b.a_(OfflineInstallJobCleanup.java:26)
07-10 05:48:50.118: W/System.err(3461):     at com.facebook.oxygen.common.packages.b.c.a(DeltaPackageListenerDispatcher.java:46)
07-10 05:48:50.118: W/System.err(3461):     at com.facebook.oxygen.common.packages.b.e.a(DeltaPackageTracker.java:84)
07-10 05:48:50.118: W/System.err(3461):     at com.facebook.oxygen.common.packages.b.f.b(DeltaPackageWorker.java:99)
07-10 05:48:50.118: W/System.err(3461):     at com.facebook.oxygen.common.packages.b.f.a(DeltaPackageWorker.java:82)
07-10 05:48:50.118: W/System.err(3461):     at com.facebook.oxygen.common.jobqueue.a.c(JobQueueManager.java:297)
07-10 05:48:50.118: W/System.err(3461):     at com.facebook.oxygen.common.jobqueue.a.b(JobQueueManager.java:270)
07-10 05:48:50.118: W/System.err(3461):     at com.facebook.oxygen.common.jobqueue.JobQueueService.a(JobQueueService.java:84)
07-10 05:48:50.118: W/System.err(3461):     at androidx.core.app.j$a.a(JobIntentService.java:397)
07-10 05:48:50.118: W/System.err(3461):     at androidx.core.app.j$a.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:387)
07-10 05:48:50.118: W/System.err(3461):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
07-10 05:48:50.118: W/System.err(3461):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
07-10 05:48:50.118: W/System.err(3461):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
07-10 05:48:50.118: W/System.err(3461):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
07-10 05:48:50.118: W/System.err(3461):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
07-10 05:48:50.140: W/main(3480): type=1400 audit(0.0:521): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_mpctl_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=16646 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_mpctl_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
07-10 05:48:50.146: E/libc(3480): Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.at_library"
07-10 05:48:50.155: D/AndroidRuntime(3480): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
07-10 05:48:50.181: I/ActivityManager(1570): Force stopping com.google.android.apps.mtaas.loginutil appid=10344 user=0: start instr
07-10 05:48:50.199: I/ActivityManager(1570): Start proc 3646:com.google.android.apps.mtaas.loginutil/u0a344 for added application com.google.android.apps.mtaas.loginutil
07-10 05:48:50.208: E/mtaas.loginuti(3646): Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
07-10 05:48:50.221: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): mCompatibilityFlags - 1b
07-10 05:48:50.221: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationDensity - 160
07-10 05:48:50.221: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationScale - 3.0
07-10 05:48:50.242: I/mtaas.loginuti(3646): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
07-10 05:48:50.270: I/Perf(3646): Connecting to perf service.
07-10 05:48:50.287: D/LoginUtil(3646): Removing Account {name=2D75ACMWOB43JAECIMOSBRESWI-00@cloudtestlabaccounts.com, type=com.google}
07-10 05:48:50.307: I/ActivityManager(1570): Start proc 3662:com.google.android.apps.auth.test.support/u0a345 for service com.google.android.apps.auth.test.support/.services.AccountService
07-10 05:48:50.315: E/th.test.suppor(3662): Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
07-10 05:48:50.328: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): mCompatibilityFlags - 1b
07-10 05:48:50.328: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationDensity - 160
07-10 05:48:50.328: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationScale - 3.0
07-10 05:48:50.331: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): mCompatibilityFlags - 1b
07-10 05:48:50.331: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationDensity - 160
07-10 05:48:50.331: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationScale - 3.0
07-10 05:48:50.355: I/th.test.suppor(3662): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
07-10 05:48:50.388: I/Perf(3662): Connecting to perf service.
07-10 05:48:50.398: D/DhcpClient(1570): Received packet: 00:08:22:a2:8d:3e NAK, reason requested address not available
07-10 05:48:50.410: E/ActivityThread(3662): Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.common.testing.services.storage.testargs
07-10 05:48:50.410: W/AuthService(3662): [TestArgsHelper] Error when calling AndroidTestUtil.getTestArgs(). Note that this behavior might be expected.
07-10 05:48:50.431: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): mCompatibilityFlags - 0
07-10 05:48:50.431: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationDensity - 480
07-10 05:48:50.431: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationScale - 1.0
07-10 05:48:50.452: I/AuthService(3662): [RemoveAccountOperation] Removing account: Account {name=2D75ACMWOB43JAECIMOSBRESWI-00@cloudtestlabaccounts.com, type=com.google}.
07-10 05:48:50.456: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): mCompatibilityFlags - 0
07-10 05:48:50.457: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationDensity - 480
07-10 05:48:50.457: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationScale - 1.0
07-10 05:48:50.497: I/AccountManagerService(1570): the accounts changed, sending broadcast of android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED
07-10 05:48:50.505: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): mCompatibilityFlags - 0
07-10 05:48:50.505: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationDensity - 480
07-10 05:48:50.505: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationScale - 1.0
07-10 05:48:50.516: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): mCompatibilityFlags - 0
07-10 05:48:50.517: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationDensity - 480
07-10 05:48:50.517: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationScale - 1.0
07-10 05:48:50.533: D/MusicLifecycle(18015): com.google.android.music.awareness.AwarenessRouter$2 generated event: Broadcast received with context com.google.android.music.ui.PhoneMusicApplication@7286b98 and intent Intent { act=android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED flg=0x5000010 }
07-10 05:48:50.540: I/AuthService(3662): [AccountService] Execution time for remove account is 124 ms.
07-10 05:48:50.541: W/Icing(16250): Package com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox targets Android P and isn't allowed to use AppDataSearch indexing API
07-10 05:48:50.545: I/ConfigStore(651): android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
07-10 05:48:50.546: I/chatty(651): uid=1000(system) /system/bin/surfaceflinger identical 1 line
07-10 05:48:50.547: I/ConfigStore(651): android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
07-10 05:48:50.552: D/LoginUtil(3646): Instrumentation completed successfully
07-10 05:48:50.554: I/ActivityManager(1570): Force stopping com.google.android.apps.mtaas.loginutil appid=10344 user=0: finished inst
07-10 05:48:50.554: I/ActivityManager(1570): Killing 3646:com.google.android.apps.mtaas.loginutil/u0a344 (adj 0): stop com.google.android.apps.mtaas.loginutil
07-10 05:48:50.555: W/libprocessgroup(1570): kill(-3646, 9) failed: No such process
07-10 05:48:50.558: W/Binder(1570): Outgoing transactions from this process must be FLAG_ONEWAY
07-10 05:48:50.558: W/Binder(1570): java.lang.Throwable
07-10 05:48:50.558: W/Binder(1570):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1116)
07-10 05:48:50.558: W/Binder(1570):     at android.app.IInstrumentationWatcher$Stub$Proxy.instrumentationFinished(IInstrumentationWatcher.java:164)
07-10 05:48:50.558: W/Binder(1570):     at com.android.server.am.InstrumentationReporter$MyThread.run(InstrumentationReporter.java:86)
07-10 05:48:50.561: I/Icing(16250): updateResources: need to parse akak{com.google.android.gms}
07-10 05:48:50.561: D/AndroidRuntime(3480): Shutting down VM
07-10 05:48:50.566: D/MusicLifecycle(18015): com.google.android.music.eventlog.MusicEventLogger$1 generated event: Broadcast received with context com.google.android.music.ui.PhoneMusicApplication@7286b98 and intent Intent { act=android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED flg=0x5000010 }
07-10 05:48:50.581: W/CurrentAccountHolder(3481): [main] Account has been reset
07-10 05:48:50.586: I/ProvidersCache(3422): Provider returned no roots. Possibly naughty: com.google.android.apps.docs.storage
07-10 05:48:50.591: W/libprocessgroup(1570): kill(-3646, 9) failed: No such process
07-10 05:48:50.608: I/Zygote(541): Process 3646 exited due to signal (9)
07-10 05:48:50.609: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): mCompatibilityFlags - 0
07-10 05:48:50.609: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationDensity - 480
07-10 05:48:50.609: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationScale - 1.0
07-10 05:48:50.624: D/BoundBrokerSvc(12968): onBind: Intent { act=com.google.android.contextmanager.service.ContextManagerService.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
07-10 05:48:50.624: D/BoundBrokerSvc(12968): Loading bound service for intent: Intent { act=com.google.android.contextmanager.service.ContextManagerService.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
07-10 05:48:50.634: W/libprocessgroup(1570): kill(-3646, 9) failed: No such process
07-10 05:48:50.635: I/libprocessgroup(1570): Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10344 pid 3646 in 79ms
07-10 05:48:50.637: W/Icing(16250): Package com.google.android.music targets Android P and isn't allowed to use AppDataSearch indexing API
07-10 05:48:50.660: D/MusicLifecycle(18015): com.google.android.music.AccountsBroadcastReceiver generated event: Broadcast received with context android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@6051f78 and intent Intent { act=android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED flg=0x5000010 cmp=com.google.android.music/.AccountsBroadcastReceiver }
07-10 05:48:50.664: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): mCompatibilityFlags - 0
07-10 05:48:50.664: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationDensity - 480
07-10 05:48:50.664: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationScale - 1.0
07-10 05:48:50.670: I/SignupStatusTask(18015): Starting 'com.google.android.music.sync.google.MusicGcmTaskService
07-10 05:48:50.680: D/DhcpClient(1570): Received packet: 00:08:22:80:09:03 NAK, reason requested address not available
07-10 05:48:50.692: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): mCompatibilityFlags - 0
07-10 05:48:50.692: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationDensity - 480
07-10 05:48:50.692: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationScale - 1.0
07-10 05:48:50.692: D/AwarenessRouter(18015): 0 new fences
07-10 05:48:50.694: I/A(18106): GMSCore Auth returned 0 accounts.
07-10 05:48:50.694: I/A(18106): GoogleOwnersProvider returned 0 accounts.
07-10 05:48:50.694: I/ActivityManager(1570): Killing 23349:com.android.vending:background/u0a57 (adj 906): empty #17
07-10 05:48:50.695: W/libprocessgroup(1570): kill(-23349, 9) failed: No such process
07-10 05:48:50.714: I/ActivityManager(1570): Start proc 3689:com.android.email/u0a130 for broadcast com.android.email/.service.EmailBroadcastReceiver
07-10 05:48:50.715: D/AwarenessRouter(18015): 0 fences already registered
07-10 05:48:50.716: D/ConnectivityService(1570): ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=108, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Unwanted:  Uid: 10057] ], android.os.BinderProxy@915066c)
07-10 05:48:50.716: D/ConnectivityService(1570): releasing NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=108, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Unwanted:  Uid: 10057] ] (release request)
07-10 05:48:50.718: I/Zygote(541): Process 23349 exited due to signal (9)
07-10 05:48:50.720: D/QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager(2422): handleMessage what = 1
07-10 05:48:50.722: I/QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel(2422): [0]invokeOemRilRequestRaw: serial=1112 length=24
07-10 05:48:50.723: I/QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel(2422): [0]processOemHookResponse serial no: 1112 error: 0length=0
07-10 05:48:50.724: D/QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager(2422): handleMessage what = 2
07-10 05:48:50.726: D/AwarenessRouter(18015): Successfully removed 0 context fences
07-10 05:48:50.726: I/QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel(2422): [0]processOemHookIndication length=28
07-10 05:48:50.727: D/QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager(2422): handleMessage what = 0
07-10 05:48:50.730: E/m.android.emai(3689): Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
07-10 05:48:50.742: W/libprocessgroup(1570): kill(-23349, 9) failed: No such process
07-10 05:48:50.742: I/libprocessgroup(1570): Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10057 pid 23349 in 47ms
07-10 05:48:50.746: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): mCompatibilityFlags - 0
07-10 05:48:50.746: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationDensity - 480
07-10 05:48:50.746: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationScale - 1.0
07-10 05:48:50.750: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): mCompatibilityFlags - 0
07-10 05:48:50.750: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationDensity - 480
07-10 05:48:50.750: D/CompatibilityInfo(1570): applicationScale - 1.0
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106): Input Future failed with Error
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/contentcapture/ContentCaptureManager;
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     at com.google.android.apps.search.assistant.verticals.b.h.<init>(PG:1)
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     at com.google.android.apps.search.assistant.verticals.b.i.<init>(PG:1)
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.binaries.velvet.app.amf.lb(PG:4)
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     at com.google.apps.tiktok.j.b.v.o(PG:2)
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     at com.google.apps.tiktok.j.b.v.h(PG:2)
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     at com.google.apps.tiktok.j.b.o.apply(Unknown Source:4)
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     at com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.ef.apply(PG:2)
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.i.e(PG:2)
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.j.run(PG:9)
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     at com.google.android.libraries.i.ah.run(PG:1)
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     at com.google.android.libraries.i.e.run(PG:2)
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     at com.google.android.libraries.i.s.run(PG:4)
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.contentcapture.ContentCaptureManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox-WOAT9uS6UrQhClzAyD07Ig==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox-WOAT9uS6UrQhClzAyD07Ig==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox-WOAT9uS6UrQhClzAyD07Ig==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
07-10 05:48:50.760: E/m(18106):     ... 15 more
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106): Updating sync accounts failed. Some accounts may not sync correctly.
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/contentcapture/ContentCaptureManager;
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.s(PG:6)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.get(PG:4)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.eb.a(PG:1)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ci.r(PG:2)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.apps.tiktok.j.b.v.i(PG:1)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.apps.tiktok.j.b.i.run(Unknown Source:2)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.ea.run(PG:2)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.bf.execute(PG:1)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.i(PG:1)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.ip(PG:5)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.apps.tiktok.j.b.v.d(PG:14)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.apps.tiktok.j.b.ag.b(PG:1)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.apps.tiktok.account.data.manager.ae.m(PG:6)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.apps.tiktok.account.data.manager.p.apply(PG:3)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.eg.apply(PG:2)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.h.e(PG:2)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.j.run(PG:9)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.android.libraries.i.ah.run(PG:1)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.android.libraries.i.e.run(PG:2)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.android.libraries.i.s.run(PG:4)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/contentcapture/ContentCaptureManager;
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.android.apps.search.assistant.verticals.b.h.<init>(PG:1)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.android.apps.search.assistant.verticals.b.i.<init>(PG:1)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.binaries.velvet.app.amf.lb(PG:4)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.apps.tiktok.j.b.v.o(PG:2)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.apps.tiktok.j.b.v.h(PG:2)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.apps.tiktok.j.b.o.apply(Unknown Source:4)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.ef.apply(PG:2)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.i.e(PG:2)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     ... 7 more
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.contentcapture.ContentCaptureManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox-WOAT9uS6UrQhClzAyD07Ig==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox-WOAT9uS6UrQhClzAyD07Ig==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox-WOAT9uS6UrQhClzAyD07Ig==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
07-10 05:48:50.767: E/A(18106):     ... 15 more
```

Comment: is this a recurring problem or a one time crash?

Comment: so far it's a one time crash, but I can't predict whether it will recur in the future.

Comment: I personally wouldn't waste a lot of time on a one-time crash.  Especially given how weird that crash report is - I'd consider it an anomaly unless it happens again

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jason, I'll put it aside then, at least until it appears again. Cheers!

Comment: I'm also getting same problem. 

ANR in com.google.android.apps.messaging;PID: 11905;Broadcast of Intent { act=android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED flg=0x5000010 cmp=com.google.android.apps.messaging/com.google.apps.tiktok.account.data.device.DeviceAccountsChangedReceiver_Receiver };

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. This post seems to suggest that it is nothing to do with the user code, or Tiktok,, but an internal Google component that cannot be removed  - so impossible to fix. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64931177/2821954